# Game Maker Language new line

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-studio-1.4

I am writing a GML script and wanted to know how to make a message appear on the next line:

ex.

```
show_message("Hello" + *something* + "World")
```

outputs:

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: You should probably ask this at the Game Maker forums.

Comment: @Artelius then why does StackOverflow exist? :)

Comment: @RobQuist SO was a bit different in '09 :P

Comment: @Artelius holy crap I'm gravedigging :O Sorry, trying to clean up the GML / GM tags / questions and answers here lol.

Answer (score 14):

For **GameMaker: Studio 2**, always use `\n` as new line.

```
show_debug_message("First Line\nSecond Line");
```

For **earlier releases**, always use `#` as new line.

```
show_message("First Line#Second Line");
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not positive (never used Game Maker before) but the manual appears to state that a # will work (though that may only work for draw_string). You can also try Chr(13) + Chr(10), which are a carriage return and linefeed.

So, you could try:

```
show_message("Hello#World")
```

or

```
show_message("Hello" + chr(13) + chr(10) +"World")
```

From: http://gamemaker.info/en/manual/gmaker

Answer (score 3):

Despite the other mentioned methods are more "correct", in Game Maker you can also write the new line straight in the code editor:

```
show_message("Hello
World");
```

But codes get a bit messy this way.

Answer (score 2):

To create a new line use # So for example

To print this:

```
Hello
World
```

Use this:

```
show_message('Hello#World');
```

Answer (score 1):

Game Maker 1.4 can use the pound sign for newlines, as well as the linefeed character (`chr(10)`):

```
show_debug_message("Hello#World");
show_debug_message("Hello" + chr(10) + "World");
```

Since GameMakerStudio 2 you can now use escaped characters;

```
show_debug_message("Hello\nWorld");
show_debug_message("Hello#World"); //Will not work, the pound sign is now literal!
show_debug_message("Hello" + chr(10) + "World");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `#` to start a new line:

```
show_message("Hello World!")
```

Would come out like this:

```
Hello World!
```

However,

```
show_message("Hello#World!")
```

Would come out like this:

```
Hello
World!
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated you can use `"string#this is in a new line"`
If you want to use a hashtag as text and not newline use `\#`

[You can look up more information about strings here.](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/strings/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Here's another example.  Instead of having a message box come up, you could use the function `draw_text(x,y,string)`

An example of this would be: `draw_text(320,320,"Hello World");`

Hope this helps

Comment: Not what the user is asking for.